# Is there a way to delay some tasks while leaving others running? C

Tags: c, delay

I am working on a project where I need to change values periodically with a delay, but need to keep updating other info while waiting. For example updating a 7-segment display with multiplexing while setting a delay between button reads to increment or decrement the number.

In this example I want to compare a pressure sensor value with my preset table, and according to that, turn on the solenoid or turn it off (On time and Off time), for example on for 500ms and 0ff for 500ms while not interrupting other updates.

My aim is to read the pressure when the solenoid is off so I only read the pressure from the tire. Thats why I want to turn the solenoid off to read and back on to inflate according to the read value.

```
onTime = 100; offTime = 0;
onTimeCheck = 200; offTimeCheck = 200;

if (adc < tableValue && onTime == onTimeCheck)
{
   PORTB.B0 = 1;  // Turn on solenoid
   onTime = 0;    // Reset
   DisUpdate();   // Update 7-segment
}

else if (adc < tableValue && offTime == offTimeCheck)
{
   PORTB.B0 = 0;  // Turn off solenoid
   offTime = 0;   // Reset
   readPressure();// Read the pressure sensor when solenoid is off
   DisUpdate():   // Update 7-segment
}

// Increment offTime to add up
if (offTime < offTimeCheck)
{
   offTime++;
}
else if (offTime = offTimeCheck){}

// Increment onTime to add up         
if (onTime < onTimeCheck)
{
   onTime++;
}
else if (onTime = onTimeCheck){}
```

I did something like this to read the switches at a slower rate than the multiplex speed of the 7-segment, but it doesnt seem to be working any way I try this.

Comment: Multithreading?

Comment: I am working on a pretty limited microcontroller, do you think it might work?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Might work. Might not. It was just a guess. Start by checking if running two threads is even possible.

Comment: If you don't have an operating system you could implement your own scheduling by creating a loop that executes the tasks alternatingly or in specific intervals. Implement long-running tasks as functions that do it step-by-step over multiple calls with some internal state.

Comment: Learn about finite state machines, separate concerns, and implement separated function in independent modules.

Comment: Apart form the state machine, you might want to implement a *todo* action-queue, and loop eternally processing this queue.

Comment: Do you have access to peripherical like general purpose clock or systick?